# emre1512 Noty RelativeLayout creation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, noty

I have a simple MainActivity with a simple main layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need to activate [Noty](https://github.com/emre1512/Noty) on this activity. What I need to know is how to create RelativeLayout "yourLayout" in its simple exmple in Kotlin.

```
Noty.init(YourActivity.this, "Your warning message", yourLayout, Noty.WarningStyle.SIMPLE).show();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `android:id` attribute to your `ConstraintLayout` tag:

```
android:id="@+id/root"
```

Now you can fetch a reference to that `ConstraintLayout` in code:

```
val root: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.root)
Noty.init(this@MainActivity, "Your warning message", root, Noty.WarningStyle.SIMPLE).show()
```